# SSL packets monitoring

Tags: ssl, zap

I am testing SSL on the localhost server.

It looks like HTTPS is displayed in the address bar and it seems to be successful HTTPS communication.

However, when I use ZAP to break the request and  response, and see them the contents are just plain text.

Is this the right thing?

[image]

Comment: If you (or anyone) installed ZAP's CA cert, it can MitM (decrypt) HTTPS. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147250/why-are-https-requests-blocked-by-firefox-when-using-zap-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the https part of the URL has a red line across it I'm guessing you launched the browser from ZAP. When you do that ZAP configures the browser to proxy via ZAP and ignore certificate warnings. ZAP can then use its CA certificate to intercept and re-sign the request.